# Where can I see the results of data collected by Measurement Protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm using the following things to send a successful hit:

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/

`v=1&t=event&tid=UA-MY_ID&cid=server&value=error`

Problem is I can't find my hit anywhere in the Google Analytics interface. Which graph or tab or setting should I look for to find the data collected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the code in your post the actual payload, you had used, or just an example? It does not seem to be a valid hit. If you'd like to send an event, then event category and event action are required fields. You can check the parameter reference [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events). The Hit Builder should also help you to verify required fields.

Nevertheless, you should check the Real-Time / Events to see incoming traffic of event type hits. To look for all collected events, a good place to start is Behavior / Events / Top events, where you'll see the volume and value of all collected events. This latter report might take some time to be populated, up to 48 hours per Google Analyitcs (free version) SLAs. For smaller sites you can still see some intra-day data.

For pageviews the best places to start are similarly Real-Time / Content, And Behavior / Site Content / All pages.

If the realtime reports are empty, you should also check your view filter settings, to verify, if you haven't filtered your traffic, e.g. by IP address.

**Edit**

This is a [valid hit](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-111111-1&cid=server&value=error&dummy=dummy), with some non Analytics parameters and values, still not showing up in Analyitcs. (Although there's an info in [debug view](https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-111111-1&cid=server&value=error&dummy=dummy) about the value and dummy parameters.)

```
v=1&t=event&tid=UA-111111-1&cid=server&value=error&dummy=dummy
```

This is also a [valid hit](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-111111-1&cid=server&value=error&dummy=dummy&ec=cat), which shows up in realtime view, as event category is set (ec)

```
v=1&t=event&tid=UA-111111-1&cid=server&value=error&dummy=dummy&ec=cat
```

Comment: Actual payload, but with my site's google analytics Id. It is a valid hit when I change the Id. I checked real-time events and couldn't see there.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not submitting event category? Although the hit passes the validator, it seems to be the reason for not showing up in your property. (Assuming no view filters are in effect.)

Comment: Because it was marked as optional in the doc. So I thought I could just try a more basic query first